# CMake identifies MSVC (both C and CXX), but still throws 'No CMAKE_*_COMPILER found'

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been searching around, and this issue seems to come up a lot in various forms. It was most often caused by a missing compiler, which would say C and CXX compilers are `unknown`.

In my case however, that's not what's happening. I have C and C++ compilers on my machine, and e.g. through Visual Studio everything compiles fine. Through `cmake` however, this happens:

```
> cmake .
```

Output:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm a bit confused. How can it find the compiler, but then forget about it? There are also no errors in the output log (or if there *are*, I don't recognize them).

These are the very last lines in `CMakeOutput.log`:

```
Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.exe"
Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "CompilerIdCXX.vcxproj"
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC, found in "[...]/CMakeFiles/3.9.1/CompilerIdCXX/CompilerIdCXX.exe"
```

---

The source `CMakeLists.txt` is part of an existing, working project, so I'm led to believe this is a local configuration issue.

---

### Update

Manually specifying these compilers as the following will make cmake discover them and generate the project (real paths are used here on purpose, as I suspect the paths themselves can be perhaps the cause of this error, note the foreign characters):

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "D:/Programfájlok (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "D:/Programfájlok (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin")
```

*Note: these go at the top of the `CmakeLists.txt` file.*

The question still stands as in why can't cmake determine these paths automatically, when it *can* determine the correct generator.

### Update 2

According to the FAQ, it is [not recommended to set compiler paths in CmakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#How_do_I_use_a_different_compiler.3F), so another approach can be the following:

```
cmake
    -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="path/to/compiler"
    -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="path/to/compiler"
    ..
```

Comment: Are you running this in a Visual Studio command prompt so you have the environment setup?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I've tried both MSBuild Command Prompt and Developer Command Prompt, both with and without admin mode.

Comment: What version of CMAKE?

Comment: @RetiredNinja `cmake --version > 3.9.1`

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your Visual Studio installation. On a working installation, CMake should be able to detect the compiler correctly from the plain command prompt (you don't even need to open the VS dev command prompt, as it extracts all the relevant info from the system-wide environment variables). Are you able to compile a trivial *Hello World* project with CMake on that machine?

Comment: @ComicSansMS -- Nothing happens, same message with a trivial test project (any project). Tried reinstalling VS, cmake, nothing helps.

Comment: Please take a look to the following answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26542236/1516116 I guess you have to call vsvars32.bat to update the system path.

Comment: @ValidusOculus Thanks for the link, tried doing that, but no change (not even after restart).

Comment: Please make sure you actually [installed the relevant C++ components for Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36269673/no-console-application-in-visual-studio-2015/36269895#36269895). They are off by default and easy to miss.

Comment: `CMakeCache.txt` may hint on where the problem is - could you post that, on pastebin perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been previous reports of CMake's Visual Studio generators breaking due to unicode paths ([here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2013-February/053536.html), [here](http://www.vtkedge.org/Bug/view.php?id=10180&history=1)), and while this issue seems to be long fixed ([CMake commit](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commit;h=cdc29c3)), it could indicate that Unicode paths may be still causing trouble in some cases.

Based on your description, it doesn't sound like an installation issue - a fresh Visual Studio installation, that otherwise works properly. Since when specifying `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` manually, the build is working, my best guess would be that there's may be something to do with CMake's compiler detection involving Unicode paths.

The above is just an educated guess. However, if it's your own project, and/or you have control on how CMake is invoked, specifying the compilers to CMake with `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` is perfectly fine.

> How can it find the compiler, but then forget about it?

The macro in charge of determining the compiler version is called  `CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID` (in [CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake)). Going through the macro code, there are several defines that should be set during normal operation, namely `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID`, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_TOOL`. In your case, it seems that `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` are set, but for some reason `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_TOOL` isn't:

```
  # Display the final identification result.
  if(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_ID)
    if(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_VERSION)
      set(_version " ${CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_VERSION}")
    else()
      set(_version "")
    endif()
    message(STATUS "The ${lang} compiler identification is "
      "${CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_ID}${_version}")
  else()
    message(STATUS "The ${lang} compiler identification is unknown")
  endif()

  # Check if compiler id detection gave us the compiler tool.
  if(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_ID_TOOL)
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER "${CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER_ID_TOOL}" PARENT_SCOPE)
  elseif(NOT CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER)
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER "CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" PARENT_SCOPE)
  endif()
```

`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_TOOL` is set by the `CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD` macro, in that same file. There's quite some code involved in setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_TOOL` (running a process, capturing its output, regex matching, etc.), so it's theoretically possible that some of it (or even the invoked Visual Studio commands) doesn't behave well with Unicode paths.